# Project Professional Versioning Settings not letting more than one version (invalid number)

Tags: 2010, project-server, ms-project

In additional settings, I want to add another version number (12.0.xxxx.xxxx for *MS Project 2007*) from the "***Professional Versioning Settings***" option, which already has a *MS Project 2010* version number (14.0.xxxx.xxxx).

My issue is that I can't add more than one, since it says "invalid version number". Either I add the 12.0 or the 14.0, but I can't add them both.

The odd thing was that before I changed it, it already had the two versions, but after I changed it, I can't add them again (I did it to get access with my MS Project version).

Do I need to change something in somewhere else?

Comment: Could you provide an image please? Are you separating by comma?

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I already fixed it.

Turns out I was introducing a wrong version by a number (though I copy pasted it before I changed it).

IE: Instead of 12.0.4563.1000, it was 12.0.4565.1000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was introducing a wrong version by a number (though I copy pasted it before I changed it).

IE: Instead of 12.0.4563.1000, it was 12.0.4565.1000.

Sorry for wasting your time.